# Missing "Disk options (advanced)" on Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, installation, formatting

I wanted to install Windows 7 and format the disk partition while doing so. My problem is that advanced disk options are missing. Here is a screen shot:
 [image: Here is my installation screenshot] 
And here is how it should look:
[image: here is how it should look] 
I probably missed something.

Comment: Did you boot it from DVD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boot from windows DVD and you'll be able to format it. You screenshot shows that "To make change to partition, restart windows from installation disc"

[image]